# jQuery/JS Find elements which submit forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I made a jQuery plugin which reprograms forms' submit buttons to use ajax requests.

The problem appears when submit button isn't a `<submit>` element, like this:

```
<div class="home" onclick="document.form.submit()">
     <h2>Save</h2>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to find these elements in an *"elegant"* way?

Comment: Why can't you just intercept the submit event with onSubmit, and then prevent the default action? http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: you should attach a callback to the .subbmit() event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than modifying all the elements that may trigger form submission, you can bind to the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event on the `<form>` itself:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Inhibit default submission.
    // Now submit form through AJAX...
});
```

Comment: I knew there has to be some easier way! Thanks!